# Corona SDK - Pop Up Window (with Director Class)

Tags: coronasdk

I am new to game development and I am trying to create a simply GUI framework for my current project. I am currently using the Director Class 1.4 for my scene management. I have got my project o change scenes, but now I want to create a pop up window. I just want the pop up window to show up over the current scene I'm on. Below is the code for my main.lua and menu.lua (my initial scene). If anyone could help me out, I would really appreciate it. Please try to be as specific as possible, because I am very new to Corona and programming in general.

main.lua

```
_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight

local director = require ("director");

local mainGroup = display.newGroup();

local function main()

mainGroup:insert(director.directorView);

director:changeScene("menu");

return true;
end

main();
```

menu.lua

```
module(..., package.seeall)

function new()
    local localGroup = display.newGroup();

    local bg = display.newImage("Images/background1.PNG");  

    local myText = display.newText("Merchant", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 24)
    myText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)
    myText:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint);
    myText.x = _W/2; myText.y = _H/2;

    local hero_btn = display.newImage("Images/weaponcraft.PNG", 25, 25);
    hero_btn:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint);
    hero_btn.x = 252; hero_btn.y = 475;
    hero_btn.scene = "heroMain";

    local craft_btn = display.newImage("Images/smithing.PNG", 25, 25);
    craft_btn:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint);
    craft_btn.x = 7; craft_btn.y = 475; 
    craft_btn.scene = "craftMain";

    local inventory_btn = display.newImage("Images/inventory1.png");
    inventory_btn:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint);
    inventory_btn.x = _W/2; inventory_btn.y = 430;
    --inventory_btn.scene = "inventory";

    function changeScene(e)
        if(e.phase == "ended") then
            director:changeScene(e.target.scene);
        end
    end     

    localGroup:insert(bg);
    localGroup:insert(hero_btn);
    localGroup:insert(craft_btn);

    hero_btn:addEventListener("touch", changeScene);
    craft_btn:addEventListener("touch", changeScene);

    return localGroup;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `native.showAlert` function.  This shows a popup dialog box.

Something like this:

```
local function onComplete( event )

local action = event.action
if "clicked" == event.action then
    if 1 == event.index then

    end
end

local alert = native.showAlert( "You are in scene1!", "Congratulations!", { "OK" }, onComplete )
```

This show a dialog box with a "You are in scene1!" title,  "Congratulations!"  subtitle, and a "OK" button that closes the dialog box when you click(or tap) it.

Put these code in the front of your scene, and change the `native.showAlert` properties to the words you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom pop up and can handle it by your own I am putting the sample code.

```
--function to create a dialog to be shown on the game over
local function gameOverAlertScreen()
    --Display item used in the popup screen
    local alertBox , restartBtn, levelBtn, soundOnOffSwitch, quitOnOffSwitch, imageSheetSoundOnOff, imageSheetQuitOnOff
    --initial constans used for positioning the display items
    local startTX = -400
    local startTY = halfH
    local btnInitailY = halfH -50
    local btnMargin = 10

    --cancel the game pausse timer
    if(gameTimer_main) then
        timer.cancel(gameTimer_main)
        gameTimer_main = nil
    end

    local optionSoundSheet =
    {
        -- The params below are required
        width = 51,height = 51,numFrames = 2,-- The params below are optional; used for dynamic resolution support
        sheetContentWidth = 102,  -- width of original 1x size of entire sheet
        sheetContentHeight = 51  -- height of original 1x size of entire sheet
    }
    local optionQuitSheet =
    {
        -- The params below are required
        width = 51,height = 51,numFrames = 2,-- The params below are optional; used for dynamic resolution support
        sheetContentWidth = 102,  -- width of original 1x size of entire sheet
        sheetContentHeight = 51  -- height of original 1x size of entire sheet
    }

    isFirstTime=true
    --pauseScreen()
    dialog=true

    alertBox = display.newImage("image/popup_dialog.png")
    alertBox.x = halfW; alertBox.y = halfH
    alertBox:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)

    --creating the restart button fot the popup dialog
    restartBtn = widget.newButton{
        defaultFile="image/replay_btn.png",overFile = "image/replay_btn_hover.png",
        isEnable=true,onRelease =  onReplayBtnGameOverRelease -- event listener function
    }
    restartBtn.x = halfW
    restartBtn.y = btnInitailY

    --creating the level button
    levelBtn = widget.newButton{
        defaultFile="image/menu.png",overFile = "image/menu_hover.png",
        isEnable=true, onRelease =  onLevelBtnGameOverRelease -- event listener function
    }
    levelBtn.x = halfW
    levelBtn.y = restartBtn.y + restartBtn.height + btnMargin

    --creating the sound on off switch
    imageSheetSoundOnOff = graphics.newImageSheet( "image/sound.png", optionSoundSheet )
    soundOnOffSwitch = widget.newSwitch
    {
        left = screenW * 0.18,top = screenH * 0.73, style = "checkbox", sheet = imageSheetSoundOnOff,
        initialSwitchState = soundOn,frameOff = "2",frameOn =  "1",onRelease = onSoundButtonClicked, onPress = onSoundButtonClicked,
    }


    --creating the quit on off switch
    imageSheetQuitOnOff = graphics.newImageSheet( "image/vibration.png", optionQuitSheet )

    quitOnOffSwitch = widget.newSwitch
    {
        left = screenW * 0.7,top = screenH * 0.735,style = "checkbox",sheet = imageSheetQuitOnOff,onPress = onViberationButtonClicked,
        initialSwitchState = vibrationOn,frameOff = "2",frameOn =  "1",
    }
    --soundOnOffSwitch:setState({ isOn = soundOn })
    --quitOnOffSwitch:setState({ isOn = vibrationOn})

    --create/position logo/title image on upper-half of the screen
    local titleLogo = display.newImageRect( "image/gameover.png",144,30)
    titleLogo:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    titleLogo.x = halfW
    titleLogo.y =  btnInitailY - 65

    if popupGameOverGroup == nil then
        popupGameOverGroup = display.newGroup()
    end
    -- inserting the buttons and the alert dialog to the popup group
    popupGameOverGroup:insert(alertBox)
    popupGameOverGroup:insert(restartBtn)
    popupGameOverGroup:insert(levelBtn)
    popupGameOverGroup:insert(soundOnOffSwitch)
    popupGameOverGroup:insert(quitOnOffSwitch)
    popupGameOverGroup:insert(titleLogo)

    transition.from(popupGameOverGroup, {time =1000,x=startTX,y=titleLogo.y,xScale = 1, yScale = 1,
        transition = easing.inOutExpo})

    localGroup:insert(popupGameOverGroup)

    showAdd()
end
```